# Is there a way to use variable as input for apps script embedded chart setoptions?

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

I'm trying build and update chart on google sheet using apps script. Apps script provides all the options that I want to use but couldn't figure out how to use variable in the setOption.

```
//Option 1

  chartBuilder = chartBuilder.modify()
  .setOption('series',{ 0 :{errorBars:{magnitude:0.5, errorType:'constant'}}}).build();

//Option 2

chartBuilder = chartBuilder.modify()
.setOption('series.0.errorBars.magnitude', 0.5)
.setOPtion('series.0.errorBars.errorType', 'constant').build();

//Option 3

var i = 0;
  chartBuilder = chartBuilder.modify()
  .setOption('series',{ i :{errorBars:{magnitude:0.5, errorType:'constant'}}}).build();
```

Option 1 and 2 work but 3 doesn't. Is there a way to use variable as input? The only thing I can think of is prebuild strings using variable and use Option 2.

Comment: Upon further checking & testing on my end, it looks it is not possible to pass a variable using the structure of the setOption() method on yous sample "Option 3". Pre-building of the strings using the variable on "Option 2" looks to be the only ideal solution for your goal, like what you've hunched on your post (I've tested that it works).

Comment: have you tried do this: 
var i = 0;
chartBuilder = chartBuilder.modify()
.setOption('series',{ [i] :{errorBars:{magnitude:0.5, errorType:'constant'}}}).build();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it gonna help you; but **dynamic keys** of literal objects in javascript can be set by putting your variable into **brackets**:

```
let n = "name";
let obj = {[n] : "Peter"};

//expected {name : "Peter"}
```